# Android compiling - wrong Java version

Tags: java, android

I have tried to build Android according to [this guide](http://source.android.com/source/download.html)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk //just because installer want java 6'
```

I deleted other versions of jJava, but when I tried to make it I got this error:

> `You are attempting to build with the incorrect version of java.   Your
>   version is: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:
>   -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar . The correct version is: Java SE 1.6.   Please follow the machine setup instructions at
>       http://source.android.com/source/download.html`

What is wrong?

Comment: Try to use oracle jdk  for building android instead openjdk.

Comment: @Shriram I try it too, but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple java version on your machine and use only one at a time.
Check this blog: [Multiple java versions on single machine to build different AOSP (Android Frameworks) on Ubuntu](https://medium.com/@bhavananv/multiple-java-versions-on-single-machine-to-build-different-aosp-versions-3cee69c3f93d)

Answer (score 0):

[OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/install/) and [Java JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) are different things.

As [Initializing a Build Environment](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) mentioned:
The master branch of Android in the Android Open Source Project (AOSP) requires Java 7. On Ubuntu, use OpenJDK.

To develop older versions of Android, download and install the corresponding version of the Java JDK:

- Java 6: for Gingerbread through KitKat
- Java 5: for Cupcake through Froyo

Comment: I try  totaly remove all versions of java and install OpenJDK 7


`$ java -version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)`

And i have again 

`Your version is: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar .
The correct version is: Java SE 1.6.`

Answer (score 0):

It's being discussed here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/VKj-Nbu8y10

Basically it's the env "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS" being checked in Android Makefile.
$ aptitude search jayatana 
i   jayatana     - Java Native Library for ayatana project

You just need to unset it for the time being, or remove it if you don't need it at all.